# Construct a row reduced echelon matrix from given solution: $\vec{x}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Forward elimination changes $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ to a row reduced $R\vec{x} = \vec{d}$: the complete solution is $ \vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + c_1\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$
>
> What is the $3$ by $3$ reduced row echelon matrix $R$ and what is $d$?

Here is what I have done, since the latter 2 solutions come from the nullspace of the matrix, this means that our $R$ is in the form: $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

How do I go about finding the constants $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Won’t $\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-5&4\end{pmatrix}$ work?

Comment: I can't see why you think that R has that form, no matter where the two latter solutions come from. R is the reduced matrix of A, **not** its nilpotent part in some decomposition of some kind...

Comment: @DonAntonio If the rank of our matrix is 2 then surely we have 2 rows that are the zero rows?

Comment: @dydxx No, of course not. If a $\;3\times 3\;$ matrix has *exactly* two rows all of zeros then its rank is exactly one...!

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry... I meant to say rank one.

Answer (score 1):

When a matrix A is RREF into matrix R the entries of vector d goes directly into $x_p$(x particular.). So transpose the $x_p^T = [4,0,0] = vector d$. Furthermore, for vector x, you can gather some information about $x_(null)$ from $x=x_p + x_n$.The $x_n$ in the problem is the 
$ x_{n2} =
c_1 * 
\begin{bmatrix}
 2\\
 1\\
 0
\end{bmatrix}
$ and 
$x_{n3}= c_2 * \begin{bmatrix}
 5\\
 0\\
 1
\end{bmatrix} $
I will scheme the vector as 
$\begin{bmatrix}
 a\\
 b\\
 c
\end{bmatrix}
$ .
In the vector x_n, we know that a, is not the free variable for both vector $x_{n2} $ and $x_{n3}$, but b and c are free variable because in $x_{particular}$ row 2 and 3 are zero. Thus for $x_{n2} $ they plug in $b=1$ $c=0$, and for $x_n{n3}$ b=0, c=1. This gives us a clue on where the matrix R rank is, which is Rank R = 1. Since we know the matrix R only has 1, and has two free variable then the matrix looks something like the following:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & c_1 & c_2 \\
    0       & 0   & 0   \\
    0       & 0   & 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
To find $c_1$, $c_2$we use the pivot variables in the special solutions. 
\begin{bmatrix}
   2       & 5 & <- this is not variable\\
   1       & 0 &  <= free\\
   0       & 1 &  <=free
\end{bmatrix} 
We know that matrix R is a 3x3. So we we turn our unknown R into a linear equation, it should be a + c_1(b) + c_2(c) = ?. The free columns, free variable move to the right hand side of the equation, the switching determined the pivot variables in teh special solution. Thus c_2 = -2, and c_3 = -5.
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & -2 & -5 \\
    0       & 0   & 0   \\
    0       & 0   & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

If you have 3rd edition of Gilbert strange Linear alg text, the passage is on page 90-100. You have to understand the pivot, rank and how those two influence the free and and not free variable to see what is c_1, c_2. Also you need to understand how vector x comes from this full equation X = x(particular) + x null. If you don't understand where the vector x and how its related the matrix R then you don't really understand the exam problem. Finally, this problem does not really have a equation to solve for matrix R. This problem wants you to really understand what I describe above to get it.